# `git config --global core.autocrlf true` doesn't work

Tags: windows, git

The config is already in written:

```bash
git config --list --show-origin
file:C:/Users/ganuo/.gitconfig  core.autocrlf=true
```

However when I stages files the warning `LF will be replaced by CRLF` still show up.
I expect that having it set to true will make the message not prompting anymore. Do you know why is that? I'm on Windows.

Comment: Why do you think this is not working ? Seems the expected behavior from the doc `If you’re on a Windows machine, set it to true — this converts LF endings into CRLF when you check out code`

Comment: @Ôrel I expect that having it set to true will make the message not prompting anymore

Answer (score 3):

When you see the message that "LF will be replaced by CRLF", what Git is really saying is, "You have LF line endings in your working tree right now, but you've configured me to produce CRLF line endings instead.  Next time this file is checked out, I'll use different line endings than you have right now, and you might not like that."

In your case, by setting `core.autocrlf` to `true`, you've asked Git to write CRLF line endings in the working tree, but the tool you're using, which is likely your editor, is using LF endings.  This is actually fine, because most editors and most tools can work fine with LF line endings, and if you don't need to process those files through tools which only accept CRLF line endings (which presumably you don't), then you can just set `core.autocrlf` to `input` and possibly set `core.eol` to `lf`.

Otherwise, you can just ignore the warning, which is harmless.  To turn it off completely, set `core.safecrlf` to false.

Comment: In addition to all this, the OP can set their editor to use the lineendings they wish.

Comment: I mean, how can I mute this warning?

Comment: I've added that as the last sentence.